# JQuery: How to only apply click function to elements in the current DIV?

Tags: jquery

I have multiple divs called `.details`, and I want to apply the following click functions to them. But right now if I click on one li, all li's with the same class names change throughout all the divs called `.details`. How do I only apply the click function to the current `.details` div?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.details div.two').hide();
    $('.details div.three').hide(); 

    $('.details ul li.one').click(function () { 
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.details ul li.two').removeClass('active');
        $('.details ul li.three').removeClass('active');
        $('.details div.one').show();
        $('.details div.two').hide();
        $('.details div.three').hide(); 
    });
    $('.details ul li.two').click(function () { 
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.details ul li.one').removeClass('active');
        $('.details ul li.three').removeClass('active');
        $('.details div.one').hide();
        $('.details div.two').show();
        $('.details div.three').hide(); 
    });
    $('.details ul li.three').click(function () {   
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.details ul li.one').removeClass('active');
        $('.details ul li.two').removeClass('active');
        $('.details div.one').hide();
        $('.details div.two').hide();
        $('.details div.three').show(); 
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="details">
    <ul>
        <li class="one active"><span>Nav 1</span></li>
        <li class="two"><span>Nav 2</span></li>
        <li class="three"><span>Nav 3</span></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="one">
        <p>Content 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="two">
        <p>Content 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="three">
        <p>Content 3</p>
    </div>                                                                          
</div>
```

CSS

```
.active {background:#fff;}
```

Comment: This code is way too messy. Why don't you post your HTML code, so that we can see what we're up against?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go back to the top with [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and then come back down with [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$('.details ul li.one').click(function () { 
    $(this).closest('.details')
           .find('ul li').removeClass('active').end()
           .find('div.two, div.three').hide().end()
           .find('div.one').show();
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Similarly for the other two.

You could further clean things up with a bit of generalization and then you'd only need one `.click` call instead of three; something like this.

```
$('.details ul li').click(function () {
    var $this    = $(this);
    var $details = $this.closest('.details');
    var idx      = $details.find('li').index(this);
    $details.find('ul li').removeClass('active').end()
            .find('div:not(:eq(' + idx + '))').hide().end()
            .find('div:eq(' + idx + ')').show();
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/2zYt3/

Comment: Thanks buddy, works perfectly and condensed the codes right down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `closest` to find the nearest ancestor with the class `details` and use that to find the appropriate elements.

For example:

```
$('.details ul li.two').removeClass('active');
```

would become:

```
$(this).closest('.details').find('ul li.two').removeClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be make like this:

```
<div class="details">
    <ul>
        <li class="one active" data-divclass="one"><span>Nav 1</span></li>
        <li class="two" data-divclass="two"><span>Nav 2</span></li>
        <li class="three" data-divclass="three"><span>Nav 3</span></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="one">
        <p>Content 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="two">
        <p>Content 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="three">
        <p>Content 3</p>
    </div>                                                                          
</div>  

<script type='javascript'>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.details ul li').click(function () { 
            var $this=$(this);
            $('.details ul li').removeClass('active');
            $this.addClass('active');
            $('div.details div').hide();
            $('div.details div.'+$this.data('divclass')).show();
        });
    });

</script>
```

.CSS

```
.active {background-color: #999;}
div.two, div.three {display: none;}
```

demo page - http://jsfiddle.net/a868v/